# random php include script - timezone undefined, unset array or function already defined

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

> Sorry, this was a bad question that I revised to make it less localized.  I've learned to narrow down my questions to the actual cause. **If anyone could up-vote the question so I can once again ask questions on stack I would be VERY grateful**.

I keep getting an error from this line.

```
        $file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files ) ) ];
```

It throws the timezone undefined, unset array or function already defined.

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset:  5 in
>   **/home/public_html/adserve.php** on line **15**
>   adserve.php

Shared hosting so no access to the php.ini file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not random errors.  The first one pretty much tells you what you need to do to fix it.

In the second one, if line 15 of your code is this:

```
$file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files ) ) ];
```

Then your undefined offset problem lies in the fact that the highest index value in a zero-indexed array like you are using will be `count - 1`.

Thus your line should be

```
$file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files ) - 1 ) ];
```

Comment: I set it via the .htaccess file and was able to write the code function_exist. sorry for being so vauge

Answer (score 3):

The error you're receiving is because you're trying to access an index of the `$files` array that doesn't exist, in this case `5`. This is caused when the number of elements is 5, which means the indexes go from 0 -> 4.

You're using PHP's `rand()`, which is inclusive if you specify a min and max, so you need to use `count($files) - 1` as the max:

```
$file = $files[ rand( 0, (count( $files ) - 1)) ];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the timezone settings error, you need to edit your php.ini to change the date.timezone settings:

```
  date.timezone = 'America/Chicago'
```

For the notice "undefined offset", you need to check if that array value actually exists :

```
  if (!empty($files[ rand( 0, count( $files ) ) ]))
         $file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files ) ) ];
```